# Does document.write from head tag need to wait for window.onload?

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I have a big group of websites which has an include() on the `<head>` tag, this include loads the content from a file which contains javascript code, this code uses document.write().

The code on the browser looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>document.write('stuff');</script>
</head>
<body>
content
</body>
</html>
```

This seems to work fine but I was wondering if it could fail on some browser/computer, since the head tag is before the body tag, and document.write writes to the body tag. Is it possible that document.write would try to write to the body tag when this tag still wasn't loaded?

Comment: You could easily make a test case for this, you know

Comment: The best advice to give is not to use `document.write`. It is considered obsolete and "dangerous" as it by-passes the idea of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small test case that shows the answer:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    document.write('stuff'); 
    console.log("document has written from head");</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        console.log("on load function has triggered");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the output from Chrome Dev Tools console:

```
document has written from head test.html:3
on load function has triggered test.html:8
```

So yes, the code in the head section will run before the onload function.

Please note that `document.write()` is not something you want to be practicing with. In my experience, I've never had to use it. It overwrites the DOM and can be rather nasty if you don't know how it works. You should use the DOM instead.

Comment: Whilst I agree that it should be avoided, I have an example of a place where I just had to use it: a legacy application where the only source code provided does not match production (it came from some cowboy who didn't believe in such things as 'version control'). Whilst in the process of building it's replacement, we were tasked with injecting a script into every page of the legacy version (for some compliance reason), and the only kludge that worked was a document.write.

Comment: Here's a strange thing. Document.write slows down the document load when used to inject scripts synchronously. No-one thinks document.write should be used, it's now flagging warnings in Chrome. Yet 10 of the top 50 sites use it in their web pages, often to write advertising scripts into their headers. Why?

Answer (score 3):

> Does document.write from head tag need to wait for window.onload?

No, quite the opposite.

The load event will fire when the document is closed. You can't write to a closed document, so calling `write` would implicitly call `open` and erase the existing document.

> This seems to work fine but I was wondering if it could fail on some browser/computer, since the head tag is before the body tag, and document.write writes to the body tag.

`write` will write to whereever the script element is, not to the body.

In this case, however, you are writing text content (which cannot appear as a child node to the head element).

This will cause the head element to end (the end tag is optional) and the body to start (the start tag is optional) and the content to be written at the beginning of the body.

`</head>
<body>` will then be treated as invalid HTML and the browser will do its usual efforts to recover from author errors.

You can see the results in a DOM inspector:

[image]

Comment: How can the end tag for `head` and the start tag for `body` be optional? If they both are optional and if both are omitted, how can you tell where `head` ends and `body` begins?

Comment: The end of the head and start of the body is triggered as soon as a node which can’t appear in the head but can appear in the body is inserted.

Comment: Thanks. How did you learn this BTW? This is not in MDN I guess. Any sources that you can recommend?

Comment: No idea. I learned it about twenty years ago. The specification has the parsing rules, but they are less general than they used to be since they no longer involve DTDs (although the effect is the same).